# Unable to find a 'table' while the table is showing on the page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a page.

HTML element:

```
<table id="stock_ret_data" class="table table-bordered 
table-striped table-sm sortable-theme-bootstrap dataTable 
no-footer" data-sortable="" role="grid" 
aria-describedby="stock_ret_data_info" style="width: 1115px;">
```

When I try to use `beautifulsoup` to find the table using:

```
soup = bs(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
tbl = soup.find('table',{'id':'stock_ret_data'})
```

It returns empty. While the same code works for another table on the same page.

I cannot figure out what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Any chance the table is loaded via javascript after the page has loaded?

Comment: it definitely is. Check the source code of the page (with ctrl-U, not the element inspector which shows the modified DOM), the only occurences of `stock_ret_data` you'll find are in JS code

Comment: If you visit that page, you can see that initially the table doesn't exist. It takes several seconds until it appears. If you grab the HTML from that link, you can confirm it does not contain the `stock_ret_data` table.

Comment: If you use your browser's debugging tools, you can see the link from which the data actually comes. Looks like a block of JSON data, which means it would be reasonably easy to parse yourself.

Comment: @Aaron, thanks I will from now on check that first. Guess I need to look into how to get the table when loaded by JS.

Comment: @larsks thanks I will try to figure out how to get the JSON response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page loads the data from this Json URL:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.rupeevest.com/mf_stock_portfolio/get_stock_detail?fincode=100002'
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to see all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for d in data['stock_data']:
    print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "s_name1": "ITI Balanced Advantage Fund-Reg(G)",
    "fund_manager_code": 541,
    "fund_house": "ITI Mutual Fund",
    "rv_sect_name": "Capital Goods",
    "fund_mgr1": "George Heber Joseph",
    "fincode": 100002,
    "compname": "ABB India Limited",
    "aum": null,
    "percent_aum": null,
    "month_name_1": null,
    "schemecode": 44362,
    "primary_fd_code": 44362,
    "month_name_2": null,
    "month_name_3": null,
    "month_name_4": 33547
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    "s_name1": "ITI Long Term Equity Fund-Reg(G)",
    "fund_manager_code": 541,
    "fund_house": "ITI Mutual Fund",
    "rv_sect_name": "Capital Goods",
    "fund_mgr1": "George Heber Joseph",
    "fincode": 100002,
    "compname": "ABB India Limited",
    "aum": null,
    "percent_aum": null,
    "month_name_1": null,
    "schemecode": 44014,
    "primary_fd_code": 44014,
    "month_name_2": null,
    "month_name_3": 1925,
    "month_name_4": 1925
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks! I was working towards a solution. This works perfectly. Have to learn about the indent.